# Is constexpr "[v[n]]sprintf" possible?

Tags: c++, printf

My intuitive answer is yes, and the implementation could also be used by a "printf". And it might be easy to overload for user-defined types.

Has anyone ever attempted this before?

Comment: Well, the `constexpr` part would be `sprintf` obviously, I'll correct the title. The rest would piggy-back on the same formatting code.

Comment: `constexpr` has lots of restriction on the function body.

Comment: The question is, how do you get a `constexpr char*` inside a variadic template. If you have solved that, it's possible. What you can do is generating a chain of `putchar` at compile time.

Comment: I'm also looking for same solution. I believe that it is possible if format string references only fixed-length data (static_assert will help). In this this case result buffer length could be computed in compile-time by summarizing format string length without placeholders, max length of string presentation of each argument and cell for null terminator. The main target is to have something like
std::array<char, _snprint_f("%d - 0x%p")> buffer;
_snprint_f(buffer, "%d - 0x%p", some_integer, some_pointer); You even could use std::array of fixed length data as argument...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can't - the main problem would be how would you get the result out of the function. When you return a string, you can actually return (1) a `new`-ed buffer (or `malloc`ed which is just as bad), (2) a static buffer or (3) fill some other buffer.

(1) is quite clearly disallowed

(2) is against the contract of `sprintf` (ie. a non-`constexpr` `sprintf` mustn't do that either)

(3) assignment is not possible in `constexpr`.

If you just want "something like `sprintf`", regardless of possibly inconvenient usage, something eg. with interface like this would work:

```
my_sprintf<my_string<'%', 'd', '%', 'c'>, my_data<int, 42>, my_data<char, 'l'> >::string_value
```

On second thought, you could avoid actually computing the string and just store the parameters of the `sprintf` invocation for later. The user would then call a non-`constexpr` method of that intermediate result if he wanted to get a `char*`, but a single character could be obtained by a `constexpr` function. That would be an unorthodox version of `sprintf`, I'm not sure if it would count at all.